# How to access struct field which is a pointer inside of a struct which is itself a pointer

Tags: pointers, go, slice

In my code below, why does `*bikeSlice[0].Type` return to me the value of the `Type` field instead of the memory address? How come `*bikeSlice[0]` returns `{Type:0xc0000641c0}` though  `*bikeSlice[0].Type` seems to automatically dereference the `Type` field?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Bike struct {
    Type *string
}

func main() {
    type1 := "road"

    bike1 := Bike{
        Type: &type1,
    }

    type2 := "mountain"

    bike2 := Bike{
        Type: &type2,
    }

    var bikeSlice []*Bike

    bikeSlice = append(bikeSlice, &bike1)
    bikeSlice = append(bikeSlice, &bike2)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *bikeSlice[0])
    fmt.Printf("%+v", *bikeSlice[0].Type)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/2Q4Bt60SUdW

Output:

```
{Type:0x40e128}
road
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think it will automatically dereference. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors

I think rule number 3 is the one you're looking for:

> As an exception, if the type of x is a defined pointer type and (*x).f is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), x.f is shorthand for (*x).f.